# Get result lies between time intervals in vespa

Tags: vespa

I have some documents inserted in vespa. All the documents have a particular timestamp(Some has 1:00 PM, some has 1:15pm etc). If I query to vespa with current timestamp and timestamp after 15 minutes interval(let it be 12:55 PM(current time) and 1:10PM in my query), then vespa must return the document with the timestamp(ie 1:00PM ) lies between them. How can I achieve it? Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See https://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/query-language.html and the range operator which works on numeric fields.